# Resta consecutiva en tabla desde postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Luego de mucho buscar me dirijo a ustedes con la esperanza de encontrar respuesta a mi pregunta.

En `postgresql` tengo el siguiente `select`:

```
SELECT *, sum(f1.unix) OVER(PARTITION BY clientmac,dia 
ORDER BY unix ROWS 
BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) as suma 
FROM tabla as f1
```

Devuelve la siguiente tabla:

[image: Resultado del select:]

Esa **query** funciona, pero mi problema es que necesito restar (y no sumar), el primer valor con el siguiente de la columna **unix** manteniendo las particiones. 
Solo he utilizado "**sum**" para hacer las pruebas de particionado

Comment: Se me ocurre una forma que tal vez sea una tontería, y es que multipliques por -1 el valor f1.unix de forma que al sumarlo obtengas la resta.

Comment: Gracias, pero no, devuelve el mismo resultado pero en negativo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tal vez puedas conjugar las funciones **lag** o **lead** para tu solución:

```
SELECT *, f1.unix - lag(unix)  OVER(PARTITION BY clientmac,dia 
ORDER BY unix ROWS 
 BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) as suma 
  FROM tabla as f1;
```

o

```
 SELECT *, f1.unix - lead(unix)  OVER(PARTITION BY clientmac,dia 
 ORDER BY unix ROWS 
 BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) as suma 
 FROM tabla as f1
```

Comment: Mil gracias, era justamente lo que me hacía falta para terminar con la query.